# View based on dynamic tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

we have a table XXX_CHARGE_DETAILS which has huge data...and have decided to backup this data into monthly tables like XXX_CHARGE_DETAILS_JAN_15 based on the month of transaction's date.

we need to create a view based on all these backup tables...Is there a way where in we can create a view that considers all backup tables created till date dynamically rather than passing statically(updating every month).

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should consider to partition the table instead of maintaining different copies by time period if performance is what you are looking for

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787(v=sql.105).aspx